# BigQuery Federated Data Source: CSV options in command-line interface?

Tags: google-bigquery, federated

When you create a federated data source using the command-line interface is it possible to specify load options like field delimiter, allow jagged rows etc.?

```
bq mk --external_table_definition=column_1:STRING,column_2:STRING@CSV=gs://my-bucket/my_files*.csv my_dataset.my_table
```

You have access to all of the csv options when you set up federated tables in the web UI or the API, have they just been left out of the command-line tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify these options in a table definition `JSON` file. You can find a lot of examples in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-table-definition#creating_a_table_definition_using_schema_auto-detect). For what you asked in the question, your `JSON` should be similar as below:

```
{
  "schema": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "column_1",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "name": "column_2",
        "type": "STRING"
      }
    ]
  },
 "csvOptions": {
    "allowJaggedRows": true,
    "fieldDelimiter": "[DELIMITER]"
  },
  "sourceFormat": "CSV",
  "sourceUris": [
    "[BUCKET_URI]"
  ]
}
```

Then just run the same command and specifying `JSON file path` instead of `inline schema`:

```
bq mk --external_table_definition=[JSON_FILE_PATH] [YOUR_DATASET.YOUR_TABLE]
```